# Android select spinner item into alert dialog and text button disappear

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I have a listview with a series of elements.
The click on an item of listview shows me a custom dialog.
In custom dialog I have a layout with:

- A spinner
- Two buttons (OK / ANNULLA)

This is the normal situation:

[image: normal situation]

When I select the spinner, he shows a list of items.

When I select an item from the spinner, the text that was present on the buttons disappear in this way:

[image: anomalous situation]

ps: this does not happen on Android 6.0, but it happens in the lower versions (such as 5.0)

The Code:

```
public void showDialogTagAssociation (Activity activity, Handler handler,
                                     String msg, final MyOperator elemento, final BluetoothDevice device,
                                     final int position){

    mHandler = handler;

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // DIALOG
    dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    //-----------------------------------------------------

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // LAYOUT
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog_custom_tag);

    **// Spinner element
    spinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner);**

    // Spinner click listener
    **spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnSpinnerItemClicked());**
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------



    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // BUTTON OK
    dialogButtonOK = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.acd_btn_ok);
    dialogButtonOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Devo assegnare il tag al nome....");
            Log.d(TAG, "Nome: " +tmpNome+"\n" +
                "TAG: "+device.getName()+" - "+device.getAddress());

            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    // BUTTON ANNULLA
    dialogButtonNO = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.acd_btn_no);
    dialogButtonNO.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------

    dialog.show();

}


**private class OnSpinnerItemClicked implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {**

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        //NOME
        tmpNome = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Thanks for the future help

Comment: Can you provide the source code!

Comment: Yes I can. I modified the question adding the code.

Comment: Do you really want to setOnItemSelectedListener to spinner. Remove that and try. but with this code I dont see any problem

Comment: Yes because I need the name selected in the spinner.
This name is saved in "tmpNome" (visible to the whole class) and when I press the button "OK" I send this name, with "sendHandlerOperatorTag" to the handler of another class.

Comment: remove that piece of code      spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnSpinnerItemClicked());     and the thing which you want will still work

Comment: Now it works.
I **removed spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener (...)** and to get the name selected by the spinner I did:

**tmpNome spinner.getSelectedItem = (). toString ();**

Thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133442/discussion-between-shuddh-and-alberto-deidda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that piece of code:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnSpinnerItemClicked());
```

and the thing which you want will still work.

Comment: The problem was that in the xml layout I had background and backgroundTint. 
The property backgroundTint had to be removed.